# What does @- mean in the following method?

Tags: ruby

I do not know the meaning of `@` in:

```
def -@
  Test.new(-@x,-@y)
end
```

What does `@` mean here?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To define [unary methods](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/doc/syntax/methods_rdoc.html) *minus*, *plus*, *tilde*, and *not (`!`)*, follow the operator with an `@` as in `+@` or `!@`. Unary methods accept zero arguments.

Example:

```
class C
  def -@
    puts "you inverted this object"
  end
end

obj = C.new

-obj # prints "you inverted this object"
```

This is how unary operator overloading is done in Ruby.

`@x` and `@y` are the instance variables of the `Test` instances. Now suppose you have the value of `@x` as `5`. So `-@x` is essentially `-5`, which is just a call to the overloaded [*unary minus*](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Fixnum.html#method-i-2D-40) method which is defined by `Fixnum` class for its instances.

Comment: [this is](http://www.rubyinside.com/rubys-unary-operators-and-how-to-redefine-their-functionality-5610.html) a huge demonstration of this technique. And read [Operator Overload](https://www.ruby-forum.com/topic/217663).

Answer (score 2):

Which `@` are you talking about?

The first one is just part of the name of the method, just like `b` is part of the name of the method in `def bar`. In particular, this is the method that is called when you use the unary prefix `-` operator, as in `-42`.

The other two are sigils indicating instance variables.

Comment: Yes, that `@` I missed to tell. I was on hurry to catch my train.. :)